# Matching certain function declarations from existing context in clang-tidy

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree, googletest, cppunit, clang-tidy

I would like to write a custom clang-tidy check to port code from cppunit to googletest.

```
class SomeTest: public CPPUNIT_NS::TestFixture {
  CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(SomeTest);
  CPPUNIT_TEST(shouldDoSomething);
  CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

...

protected:
  void shouldDoSomething();
  void otherFunction(int times = 0);
};

CPPUNITFRAMEWORK_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(SomeTest);

...

void SomeTest::shouldDoSomething() {...}
void SomeTest::otherFunction(int) {}
```

I would like to be able to replace

```
void SomeTest::shouldDoSomething() {...}
```

with

```
TEST_F(SomeTest, shouldDoSomething) {...}
```

I can match a function name from `CPPUNIT_TEST(...)` macro with

```
stringLiteral(hasAncestor(callExpr(callee(functionDecl(hasName("getTestNameFor"))))))
```

but I have no idea whether it is possible to reuse this information to match the function declaration so I can actually replace it with `googletest`.